# Obtaining data from Android sensors without Listeners

Tags: android, android-activity, sensors

I have following code:

```
public class readSensorsData extends Activity implements SensorListener {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);     

}
@Override   
public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (sensor == SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION) {

        //get orientation       

        }
        if (sensor == SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) {

         //get acceleration
             }                

        } 
        if (sensor == SensorManager.SENSOR_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {

         //get magnetic fiels
             }     
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); //results from activity
     bundle.putFloatArray("acceleration", array);

     Intent mIntent = new Intent();
     mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
     setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
     finish();
        }

  public void onAccuracyChanged(int sensor, int accuracy) {

  }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sm.registerListener(this, 
            SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION |
      SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER |
      SensorManager.SENSOR_MAGNETIC_FIELD,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    sm.unregisterListener(this);
    super.onStop();


  }
}
```

code is working but here goes my problem: when I call it from main activity in this way:

```
     Intent i = new Intent(this, readSensorsData.class);
  startActivityForResult(i, 1); //1 is for sensors     
     for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
     {
                 //do sth else here!!!!
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
      //here code for showing result from sensor activity

     }
```

then i can see 10 times result of 'doing sth else!!!' and when loop is over i can see then result from activity. So sensor activity waits for some reason and then when main activity has nothing to do, sensors are doing their job.

of course I have well implemented: onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)

I want to read sensord data directly, not using listeners, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **never** call `Thread.sleep()` in the main application thread.

Second, `startActivityForResult()` is asynchronous. The other activity will not have started when `startActivityForResult()` returns.

Third, sensor events are asynchronous.

> So sensor activity waits for some
>   reason

It cannot start until you get out of the main application thread, which is being tied up by your `Thread.sleep()` calls.

> then when main activity has nothing to
>   do, sensors are doing their job.

Precisely.

> I want to read sensord data directly,
>   not using listeners, is it possible?

No. Just use the listeners properly. [Here are three sample projects](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Sensor/) showing the use of sensor listeners.

Comment: in these examples you just use 1 activity for 1 sensor 
I want to send using Wi-Fi packet of informations to that include, orientation, acceleration etc, so besides the fact that i can not use thread.sleep() i still don't know how to get that data from sensors, can i call startActivityForResult many times, lets say in loop 1000 times, start this sctivity and destroy.. and so on. In my opinion it not efficient so how can I solve it? Maybe using service?

Comment: hmm, i think i know, i will just use thread to work with this sensors

Comment: If you want to aggregate or average data over 1000 reports, just append them to an ArrayList or something in `onSensorChanged()`. When the 1000th report comes in, then use an `AsyncTask` to perform your calculations (if any) and send the data to your server.

Comment: i want to send info from sensors, some text, other data in 1 packet
then again send the same structure of updated informations
i don't want to get 1000 results and then send it, i want take each piece of data and then send and loop it

like: for(;;){ 1)take new data from sensors; 2)send it; }